# windows 8.1 node.js JSON.parse not working right

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

i'm having some problems with the JSON.parse function in node.js on windows i'm getting this error in my command line:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ´╗┐
at Object.parse <native>
at R:\filelocation\server\server.js:13:18
at fs.js:334:14
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete <fs.js:95:15>
```

The code for loading JSON file:

```
var users;
fs.readFile('database/userDB.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    users = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

The .json file:

```
{
    "test": "test2"
}
```

The main reason why im even posting this is that it works fine on a linux server i have.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with text encoding.

Are you sure it is really saved as UTF-8 on your Windows system?

Can you open it in some text editor or a Web browser on your Windows system and verify that the encoding is what you expect? (you may need to change the file extension to .txt)

Another possible problem is a possibility of the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) characters present in the file. BOM characters are illegal in JSON but some encoding converters can put them there.

To narrow down a possible problem you can change:

```
users = JSON.parse(data);
```

to this temporarily:

```
console.log(data);
```

to see if you get what you expect.

If the text is some garbage, then it is possibly a wrong encoding. But if the text looks fine then you may have a BOM character there, which is invisible.

As some workaround you may try to remove every character before the first opening curly brace by changing:

```
users = JSON.parse(data);
```

to this:

```
users = JSON.parse(data.replace(/^[^{]+/g, ""));
```

This will not fix a bad encoding - but should remove the BOM character in case the encoding is correct but the BOM is present.

Comment: To add to this, I don't know what text editor you use, but SublimeText certainly has a lot of options to save with/without encoding. UTF-8 without BOM is one of them.

Comment: @Andy im using visual studio